# Precommit hook for svn to modify files to be committed in c#

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

I want to modify in certain way(Actually format the files in a code formatter) before they are committed to repository.
I have found out from [Precommit example](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side/PreCommit.js.tmpl) (Use guest as name and no password) how to write in python.But what i want to know is how to get list of files to be committed and other command line arguments this one takes.One more thing i prefer is to write my own pre commit hook in C# rather than Python or any other script.

Few points
I will write a exe which will format,but i want the list of files being committed
How to configure this with svn.

Comment: You should state in the question that you are talking about Tortoise side hook (example from link is a client side hook).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Precommit hooks that modify the committed files are considered 'a bad thing':

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

The idea merits a big red box in the official SVN documentation, and warns that this will affect how the SVN client works with the repository in bad ways.

Comment: It is bad, but is there a way to do this anyways?  Like to allow the commit to occur (no pre-commit); on the post-commit, it checks out the files, performs the formatting, then re-checks them back in?  Or to delete/strip executables from being checked in on pre-commit (I have people who aren't smart enough to know how to remove exe's from project, even with failing them and giving intelligent reply)?

Comment: I was asking this in regards to super-large binary files.  And because Obliterate does not yet exist.  But I have come to realize that the file would be different after manipulating it, causing it to always be out-of-date.  This would cause it to always download, even if it is the same as after (not before) it gets checked in.  If there is a way around that issue, I'm still interested.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce see my question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888667/ankhsvn-client-side-pre-commit-hook

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter passed to the pre-commit hook script is a path to a text file. That text file contains all the paths which are to be committed, separated by newlines.

But for your situation, you might better use the start-commit hook: that script is called right before the commit begins, but after the user selected the files/folders to commit. The start-commit script is called after the user clicks OK in the commit dialog, and before the actual commit begins. This hook has a list of exactly what will be committed.

Comment: Wrong! Precommit is called after the user clicks on commit on selected files. start commit is called even before the UI for list of dirty files are shown svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/…

Comment: @Ravisha: In your question you link to a CLIENT SIDE hook script, which is TortoiseSVN-specific. Somehow, I can't believe the very author of that tool would be wrong about this...

Comment: @ jeroenh 
My reply was to this statement by stefan"The pre-commit script is called when the commit dialog is shown, before the user starts selecting files/folders for committing."
Which is wrong,
Precommit is after user selects the files but before he clicks on OK button.Thats all i said.I am not saying anythin contradictory to Tortoise SVN docs

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think this is a bad idea. Why would you want to change code before a commit? in my opinion it's much better to check for code formatting/standards violations and abort the commit. I would be very frustrated if my code was changed during a commit.

To answer your specific question, use `svnlook changed` to get the list of changed files. `svnlook dirs-changed` would give you the directories affected by the pending transaction.

Comment: This is just to format the code style.It does not affect the contents in any other way.What i am doing is to beautify the class file.

Comment: svnlook won't help : he wants to use the client-side hook script feature of TSVN, not the server-side hook scripts.

Comment: +1 Original question says nothing about client-side/server-side hook.  And this is the only answer which tries to explain how to do it, even if it is something you don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you maybe already read, [a hook in subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) is just a program, called at a specifc time within the commit process with [some parameters and a return value](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html). You can place any runable program within the hook directory. So you can also place any .exe there (which can be a .Net program as well). Then check the command line arguments and do whatever you like and return any int value as errorlevel.

Within your application you can maybe use [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) or [anything else](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html) to get an easy access to the repository to make any checks and send the result to the user.