# Ankh Tortoise SVN hooks?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Basically I'm looking to fully integrate client-side pre-commit hooks inside Visual Studio with Ankh SVN. There is a question that has some guidance on the subject already: [AnkhSVN client side pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888667/ankhsvn-client-side-pre-commit-hook)

My setup is as follows:

- Visual Studio Basic 2008 - Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
- AnkhSVN - 2.3.11266
- TortoiseSVN - 1.7.7

Right now, my client-side pre-commit hook works if it's invoked outside of Visual Studio via Tortoise's folder options. I can't get the hook to invoke/process any files under source control from *inside Visual Studio* when I do a SVN commit though...

Here's my question: How do I tell Ankh to use any pre-commit hooks I've defined inside Tortoise's config though? Is there an option/screen I should be looking at?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

AnkhSVN has not implemented client-side hooks (yet?).
That's a feature that's only available in TortoiseSVN.

But there's an open issue for this:
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=453

Comment: They have the new functionality in the latest daily builds under http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/daily

Comment: The Pre and Post commit hooks are implemented in AnkhSVN 2.3 and 2.4 and will fire when the 'Enable Client Side Hooks' checkbox is enabled in Tools->Options->Source Control->Subversion Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise Client Side Hooks are only available when you use Tortoise which is why I don't like to implement them -- too client specific. They don't work if you use the Subversion command line client or built in IDE clients like AnkhSVN for VisualStudio or Subversive and Subclipse for Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestions to other Visual Studio plugins that support pre-commit client-side hooks?

Comment: @JordanChernev Nope. Even if another client does, there's no guarantee that the hooks are compatible. What are you trying to do with these client side hooks?

Comment: I need to clean up a few xml files that are generated from Visual Studio each time the project is loaded. Even if you don't change a thing, the xml generates unique ids that will make the commits to SVN from multiple people difficult.

Comment: @JordanChernev  Are these the `*.suo`, `*.user` and other types of files that populate a VisualStudio project?

Comment: No, we're using the BIDS module of VS for Analysis Services projects we develop in house. The actual files that get modified are the .dim, .cube, .partitions, .dsv, .dim and .asdatabase. We'd like to clean them up before they committed so there's less collision/chance for svn merges