# TortoiseSVN Commit through visual Studio not running hook-script

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn

I wrote a short hook-script to change the author name for each commit that I make (post_commit_hook) in my repository.

When I commit the project through Visual Studio 2015 it will not run the hook scripts. I know that this is not the best practice solution, but it's the best that I can do right now. When I commit the project outside of the Visual-Studio environment the hook script is running as expected. How can I make the commits from Visual Studio run the hook-script?

I am using AnkhSVN for source control support for Visual Studio.

Comment: Why are `you` formatting `random` words in `your` question as `code`?

Comment: Someone Edited the question that way. I don't know why.

Comment: Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888667/ankhsvn-client-side-pre-commit-hook). It might solve your problem

Comment: The edit that changed that was rather contriversial anyways. Don't forget to accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. All i had to do was to go to Tools->Options->Source Control. Select 'subversion User Tools' option and select an External Patch Tool: 'tortoiseSVN TortoiseMerge' option from the drop-down list. I hope this answer can help someone.